# Typescript: How to add type safety to object properties?

Tags: typescript, interface, type-safety

I have the following:

```
type CommandTypes = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
const CONST = {
  commands: {
    a: 'one',
    b: 'two',
    c: 'error'
  },
};
```

Is there a way to enforce that all the commands are of a particular type?

Right now TypeScript is telling me that **a**, **b**, and **c** are of type **string**, but I want to enforce those properties to be of type **CommandTypes** so that a developer can not specify an arbitrary string.  I want TypeScript to be able to catch the error that **c** is invalid since it doesn't belong to the CommandTypes that are allowed.

If I break up the CONST definition this way:

```
type CommandTypes = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
const commands : CommandTypes = {
  a: 'one',
  b: 'two',
  c: 'error'
}

const CONST = {
  commands,
};
```

Then this does in fact catch the error with **c**, however now I also lose auto completion in Visual Studio code. If I type **CONST.commands.** I don't get any auto completion here now, where as if I leave the definition as shown at the top of the post, then I do get auto completion.

Comment: Record<CommandTypes, string>
Will give you a object whos keys are CommandTypes and their values are strings

Answer (score 1):

`Record<CommandTypes, string>` will give you a object who's keys are the distributed union of CommandType and the values have to be strings. Note: you can only have a single type on the right hand side if you want different types for each key you will have to read typescripts documentation on mapped types